# preg_replace regex, split string to array

Tags: php, regex

i have a string, where i need to split some values in to an array, what would be the best aproach?

String can look like this:

```
<span class="17">118</span><span style="display: inline">.</span><span style="display:none"></span>
```

or

```
125<span class="17">25</span>354
```

The rules are:

1. The string can start with a number, followed by a span or a div
2. The string can start with a span or a div
3. The string can end with a number
4. The string can end with a /span or a /div
5. The divs/spans can have a style/class

What i need, is to seperate the string, so that i get the elements seperated, such as:

```
0 => 123
1 => <span class="potato">123</span>
2 => <span style="color: black">123</span>
```

I have tried some costum regex, but regex is not my strong side:

```
$pattern = "/<div.(.*?)<\/div>|<span.(.*?)<\/span>/";
// i know it wont detect a number value prior to the div, thats also an issue, even if it worked
```

I cannot use simple_html_dom has to be done with REGEX.

Splitting the string between every >< might work, but ">(.*?)<" inserts after the < for some reason?

Comment: Just an idea, why wouldnt you parse it as html? then you would have elements[] to use like text nodes, element nodes and so on...

Comment: What lib or function are you refering to ?

Comment: I did an example for you in answer section

Answer (score 0):

You might get better performance if you just load this string to DOM and then parse it manually programming your logic like:

```
var el = document.createElement( 'div' );
el.innerHTML = '125<span class="17">25</span>354';

// test your first element (125) index=0 (you can make for loop)
if(el.childNodes[0].nodeType == 3) alert('this is number first, validate it');
else if(el.childNodes[0].nodeType == 1) alert('this is span or div, test it');
// you can test for div or span with el.childNodes[0].nodeName

// store first element to your array

// then continue, test el.childNodes[next one, index=1 (span)...]
// then continue, test el.childNodes[next one, index=2 (354)...]
```

since you are already know are you looking for, this can be as simple as that

Comment: ups :( I didnt realize you need php, sorry. Then for the same thing I guess you need a php HTML DOM parser, shouldnt be too difficult

Comment: This one works like javascript, has childnodes and so on... http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Try `/(<(span|div)[^>]*>)*([^<]*)(<\/(span|div)>)*/`

The Regex says something like 'there can be a span or div or nothing, then it has to be somthing then a /span or /div or nothing and that whole statement can match zero or many times.

Here is an example:

```
$pattern = "/(<(span|div)[^>]*>)*([^<]*)(<\/(span|div)>)*/";

$txt = '<span class="17">118</span><span style="display: inline">.</span><span style="display:none"></span>';
preg_match_all($pattern, $txt,$foo);
print_r($foo[0]);

$txt = '125<span class="17">25</span>354';
preg_match_all($pattern, $txt,$foo);
print_r($foo[0]);
?>
```